# Saving reference in a Field

Tags: c#, reference, ref

I'm trying out the following code:

```
public partial class Test: Window
{
    public Test(ref List</* Type */> LList)
    {
        [...]
        this.ListField = LList;

    }

    private  List</* Type */> ListField;
}
```

C# doesn't save a reference in "ListField".
Example:

```
Test test = new Test(ref /* List</* Type */>-variable*/)

---------

public partial class Test: Window
{
    public Test(ref List</* Type */> LList)
    {
        [...]
        this.ListField = LList;

    }

    private  List</* Type */> ListField;

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        ListField = null;
    }
}
```

After having closed the form the Object given to `public Test(ref List</* Type */> LList)` has not changed (it's not "null").

SO how ca I save A reference in "ListField"?

Comment: So hard to understand what you mean. The code looks valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I suspect it would be hard to find examples due to terminology overloading.)

It definitely saves a reference in `ListField`. That's all it *can* do - the value of `ListField` can only ever be a reference, because `List<T>` is a class.

What it sounds like you really want is to keep the aliasing behaviour of `ref`, but that *only* applies to parameters - never fields. It's important to distinguish between "pass by reference" as a [parameter passing style](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html), and references themselves (important in terms of [the difference beteween classes and structs](http://pobox.com/~skeet/references.html)).

Basically, you can't do what you want directly. You could create a `Wrapper<T>` class, make `ListField` a `Wrapper<List<T>>` and pass a reference (by value) into the constructor, but you can't just use `ref` to do what you want.